# Would this be considered a hit and run?

Tags: united-states, california, vehicle, safety

Our vehicle was parked at our apartment complex and I noticed that there was a large scratch and dent on it. 
[image: scratch and dent Rogue]

Would this be called a hit and run? The person who did it did not leave a note or anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Hit and run" isn't a precise legal term, but there are laws against what many people call "hit and run" in California. [§20002](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&sectionNum=20002.) of the Vehicle code covers property damage without injury, and violation of the section is a misdemeanor possibly resulting in up to 6 months in prison and a $1000 fine. If you cause property damage either while driving or because it was parked and became a runaway vehicle, you are required to notify the property owner. If the owner cannot be located at the scene, you must leave your contact information and a description of the circumstances, and you must notify the police. It is irrelevant whether this was on the street or in a parking lot, because the law will "apply upon highways and elsewhere throughout the State, unless expressly provided otherwise".